# TextField not turning to dark mode in MUI5.0

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to turn a MUI <TextField /> to dark mode but even after using ThemeProvider and CSSBaseline and many solutions I couldn't figure out how to turn it to dark mode!

I tried the below code and read many q&a on this topic but am not able to debug it

To check screenshot of the output received
[image: Click here]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, CssBaseline, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#8985f2',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff4843',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
  },
});

const SignupScreen = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline /> ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Outlined"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            color="primary"
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default SignupScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what version of MUI you are using
For version ^5.4.3 , but try changing the 'type' to 'mode'.

```
    const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#8985f2',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff4843',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot this solved it  wasted so much time on this you won't believe  now I know why as I was using a mui theme generator which awas based on version 4.x.x and I didn't realise this small change in 5.x.x (I feel dumb now)

Comment: haha,, Anytime man.. 
don't feel dumb .. happens to everyone .. coding can be crazy